# Vaadin Image Upload Path

Tags: java, vaadin

How can i save my uploaded image to "src" folder not in "target" folder. i just noticed that both folders have the same directory. this is my code.

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/com/sample/global/imgfile/");
```

Everytime i uploaded the image the path is saving in this directory.

this is the directory that where the uploaded image will go.

*\target\payroll\WEB-INF\classes\com\sample\global\imgfile*

but i want the image to go to this directory instead

*\src\main\resources\com\sample\global\imgfile*

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. 
You have to be aware that when you run your application the "src" folder will no longer exists. All resources of your "/scr/main/resources" will be copied to "WEB-INF/classes/

Remember that you're deploying the application to a target server (any application server like tomcat, jetty, etc)

So, if you'd like to have some kind of "resources" folder, just create another folder with that name under the resources folder, lets say "/src/main/resources/resources". That way when you deploy the application you'll have the following structure "/WEB-INF/classes/resources".